# Bind radio button to single model preoperty in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radiobuttonfor

How do you bind 2 radio buttons to a single model property in MVC using `@Html.RadioButtonFor()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768274/correct-way-to-bind-an-mvc3-radiobutton-to-a-model

Comment: Read the first answer..I still can't understand how the correct value reaches the model property..

Comment: they should have same names. if you write radiobuttonfor, then you should pass parameter htmlattribute new { name = "a" } for both radiobuttons. It would be better to use radiobutton instead of radiobuttonfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool? DoYouAgree { get; set; }
}
```

In your view:

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DoYouAgree, false, 
        new { id = "DoYouAgree_false" })
    No
</label>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DoYouAgree, true, 
        new { id = "DoYouAgree_true" })
    Yes
</label>
```