# Is there a way to bind a complex object to radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, radio-button

I have a list of radiobuttons that I am generating from my model like this:

```
@foreach (var offer in Model.AvailableOffers)
{                    
  <div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.selectedAvailableOffer, offer)
    @Html.Label(offer.begin_date.Month + "/" + offer.begin_date.Day + " - " + offer.end_date.Month + "/" + offer.end_date.Day + ", " + offer.offer_name)
  </div>
}
```

Model includes these:

```
public List<AvailableOffer> AvailableOffers { get; set; }
public AvailableOffer selectedAvailableOffer { get; set; }
```

See how I am trying to post my `offer` object back to my controller in the `RadioButtonFor` method?  This is obviously not working, but it's what I want to accomplish.  Is there any way to post the whole selected `offer` object back to my controller or am I stuck adding some sort of ID to my object and only posting back the ID as is suggested here:

[Correct way to bind an mvc3 radiobutton to a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768274/correct-way-to-bind-an-mvc3-radiobutton-to-a-model)

Comment: Just post back the ID. Rending all the properties of each `AvailableOffer` and using javascript to make sure the correct one was posted back will degrade performance far more than a database call to get the selected `AvailableOffer` in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly: No, you can't pass whole 'offer' object back to the server. It's better to use only id's on the client side.
If you realy want to post back whole offer you can use some kind of serialization to store data from each offer object as a value of radiobutton.