# How to make listitem checked for @Html.RadioButtonFor when page loads firstly in MVC 5,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have department table with **DeptId, DeptName** and **IsSelected** Columns.

I have two records and for one of the record is selected is false and for another record isselected is true. So now when Isselected is true, value should be checked for respective record when page loads for firsttime in MVC5. I have below code, how can I modify that to achieve this requirement.

```
@model  RadioButtonForApp_MVC.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var department in Model.Departments)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.SelectedDepartments, department.DepartmentName)@department.DepartmentName
    }
<br />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic is widely descibed here: [Correct way to bind an mvc3 radiobutton to a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768274/correct-way-to-bind-an-mvc3-radiobutton-to-a-model).

But if you want quick solution, you should use [this overload of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830431(v=vs.118).aspx) RadioButtonFor which last parameter is "htmlAttributes". You can pass "checked" attribute there, so your code will look like this:

```
foreach (var department in Model.Departments)
{
    var checked = departament.IsSelected ? new {checked="checked"} : new {};
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.SelectedDepartments, department.DepartmentName,departament.DepartamentName,checked)@department.DepartmentName
}
```

Comment: Works Awesome. Thanks for the above link. I have just used below code         @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.SelectedDepartments, department.DepartmentName, department.IsSelected == true ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)@department.DepartmentName