# RadioButton Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, razorengine

Hi everyone i made an application in Asp.net that contains a fonctionaliyu that allows a candidate to register to a certain thing via a form the entity contains a property called "Gender" of type "string" in the generated view i change it like this ;

```
@Html.Label("Male")@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Male")

@Html.Label("Female")@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Female")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Is this the right way to do it??Plz  need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to bind an mvc3 radiobutton to a model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768274/correct-way-to-bind-an-mvc3-radiobutton-to-a-model)

Comment: It works, but you can improve it. Add an `id` attribute so the associated label works - e.g. `new { id = "Male" }` - or remove the default `id="Gender"` using `new { id = "" }` and wrap each button in a manual `<label>` element because duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html

Comment: This fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/jBdx43 may help you.